# Rails Get Forward/CNAME Subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, heroku, cname, forward

I have a Rails app on Heroku that uses subdomains. Let's say that my heroku domain is `example.herokuapp.com`. I have a domain called `myexample.com`. I have a second domain called `myotherexample.com`. I want to be able to:

1. Forward `myexample.com` (and `www.myexample.com`) to `example.herokuapp.com`, but have the address bar read `www.myexample.com`.
2. Forward `myotherexample.com` (and `www.myotherexample.com`) to `other.myexample.com`, but have the address bar read `www.myotherexample.com`.
3. Have Rails get the subdomain (either `other` or `''`) for use in my app.

I seem to be very confused on whether to use a CNAME, A, or just forwarding (I'm using GoDaddy as my domain provider, BTW). On another app that I have, I forward `thirdexample.com` to `www.thirdexample.com` and then CNAME it to `thirdexample.herokupp.com` and it works fine.

What do I need to do so I can retrieve the subdomain, but still hide it from the address bar? Or am I going about this wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure so someone might correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think you can mask the address in the address bar. One way of achieving what you want would be with route constraints and then somehow redirecting to the domain/path you want shown, with some query parameter that would be picked up and then redirected again, setting a cookie in the process. Or if you can have cookies work for all subdomains then that would be possible to use as well, visitor hits a certain route, which sets the cookie and gets redirected to the "viewable" domain, where you read the cookie

Comment: @MicaelNussbaumer The cookies would be different for every subdomain. Would it make sense to instead forget about subdomains and pick up on the domain itself? For instance, `myexample.com` and `myotherexample.com` would both go to `example.herokuapp.com` and then the Rails app could get either `myexample` or `myotherexample` and then go from there. Would that make it easier?

Comment: I think the only reasonable way is to decide based on your domain, in-app, you set the redirects on your domain provider to point to the heroku corresponding apps and then decide what is to be shown.